# Memory Mapped File in C#

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

I'm trying to open a file as a memory mapped file like this:

```
using (var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(newDataFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, "myTestMap"))
{
    // (bytesPerImage * numCameras) * 0 --> raw data
    // (bytesPerImage * numCameras) * 2 --> segmented left hand
    // (bytesPerImage * numCameras) * 3 --> segmented right hand
    using (var accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor((bytesPerImage * numCameras) * 0, bytesPerImage, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read))
    {
        here comes the reading and processing of the data
    }
}
```

I get the error: Process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Now, isn't the whole point of memory mapped files to share data between different processes?

From other posts I've read that you still need to synchronize the access to the data. So you have to use mutex on both the process that creates it and the process that reads it.

My problem is that the creation of this file is not under my control. It is created by the API I'm using in my project. I cannot tell the API to create it in shared mode or to name the file so that I can use `MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting`.

The developers of the API describe how to access the data in their [site](http://threegear.com/latest/doc/rawdepthdata.html#camera). In their example, they don't use any mutex to create the MMF from the file. Maybe the synchronization is done by boost??

They do recommend copying the file to another location (from which I get no error, btw) but wouldn't that cause inefficiency and maybe other kind of problems?

In the [MSDN Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) they don't use mutex on the persisted memory-mapped files examples. But they do need the name of the mmf, which I don't know (in case they've named it).

So my actual question is: Is there really no better other way to access the data than copying the file to another location every time it gets updated, create the memory mapped file, and then do the data processing?

Best Regards

Comment: The other process that opened the file has to open it in shared mode.

Comment: You can use [MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267552%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead to avoid the file locking issue.

Comment: @MatthewWatson there is no shared mode. Available modes: Append, Create, CreateNew, Open, OpenOrCreate, Truncate.

Comment: @wdosanjos: Isn't that to create the source file? That's what the API is doing. I'm the one who wants to read, not write. Or am I missing something?

Comment: `MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew` "create[s] a memory-mapped file that is not persisted (that is, not associated with a file on disk), which you can use to share data between processes." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267552%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @user752322 I meant the API that's creating the file. Or did you mean it's creating an MMF?

Comment: @MatthewWatson & @wdosanjos: I don't know if I don't understand you or you don't understand me :-) As I see it: `MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew` creates a non-persisted memory-mapped file so that one process can write information to it and another process read&write from&to it using mutex. The API I'm using creates a (Memory-Mapped) File and saves it in disk, which I think is persisted. The file is created by the API in the backgroud with no way of controlling its creation. I dont' even know if they use mutex or if the file has a system name. I edited my question a bit ...  hope is clearer now